# Show $\cos\theta=\frac12(\text{tr}(g)-1)$ with $g\in\text{SO}(3)$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

How can I show that for $g\in\text{SO}(3)$ given by $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ 0 & \sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$ the equality $$\cos\theta=\frac12(\text{tr}(g)-1)?$$

Is it sufficient to calculate the trace by $\text{tr}(g)=1+2\cos\theta\Rightarrow\text{tr}(g)-1=2\cos\theta\Rightarrow\frac{2\cos\theta}{2}=\cos\theta$ ?

Comment: ... I don't understand the question.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat What's not to understand? The OP is calculating $\frac 12(\operatorname{trace}(g) - 1)$ taking the trace (that is, finding the sum of the entries on the diagonal of the matrix), subtracting 1, and then dividing by 2 (function on the right-hand side of the equality) to show that indeed, it equals the left-hand side of the equality.

Comment: @amWhy I don't understand what is holding OP back from dividing the equality $\mathrm{tr}(g)-1=2\cos(\theta)$ by $2$...

Comment: Look more carefully to the right of the second implication: $$\frac {2\cos \theta}{2} = \cos\theta$$

Comment: @amWhy upon looking _very_ carefully I did indeed see this ^^ all joking aside, I don't understand the question, but it's fine if all doubts were cleared up by your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's exactly correct. Sometimes "proofs" that seem to be "too easy to be right" are in fact, right!

Comment: Thanks it looked too easy indeed.

Answer (score 1):

you and @amWhy are already correct.

---

Some additional notes...

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\textrm{tr}\big( a g a^{-1} \big) &=& \sum_k \big[ a g a^{-1} \big]_{kk}\\
&=& \sum_k \Big( \sum_{p,q} [a]_{kp} [g]_{pq} [a^{-1}]_{qk} \Big)\\
&=& \sum_{p,q} [g]_{pq} \Big( \sum_k  [a]_{kp} [a^{-1}]_{qk} \Big)\\
&=& \sum_{p,q} [g]_{pq} \delta_{pq}\\
&=& \sum_p [g]_{pp}\\
&=& \textrm{tr}\big(g\big).
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Let $g$ be the rotation around $\hat{x}$, and let $a$ be a rotation such that $\hat{u} = a \hat{x}$, thus a rotation around $\hat{u}$.

Then every rotation can be written as

$$
aga^{-1}
$$

and as

$$
\textrm{tr}\big(aga^{-1}\big) = \textrm{tr}\big(g\big)
$$

you and @amWhy are correct.